# Cannot dispatch event from javascript to Component (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to inform to a component that a script file had finish loading.

My idea to doing this is to use the onload event of the  element to dispatch an event. On the otherside a service will register an eventlistener to this event and will wait for clients to register themself to an observable that will notify when the event arrives.

I tried that but without success. It seems like the event is not dispatched. No errors thrown in the console.

What I am currently doing is this.

index.html:

```
<script>
function loadFinish() {
    onLoadFinish = new CustomEvent('onLoadFinish', {
      detail: { },
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: false
    });
    window.dispatchEvent(onLoadFinish);
}
</script>

<script src="opencv.js" onload="loadFinish();" type="text/javascript">
```

That loadFinish is called but i dont know if the dispatchEvent works...

The service:

```
export class JsLoadService {
    private subjectJsLoad = new Subject<any>();
    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener('onJSLoadFinish', (event) => {
            console.log("notifying...."); // this never show up in the console.
            this.subjectJsLoad.next((event as any).detail)
        })
    }

    onJsLoadFinish():Observable<any> {
        return this.subjectJsLoad.asObservable();
    }
}
```

The component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsLoadService.onJsLoadFinish().subscribe( data => {
        // also never called...
      console.log("onJsLoadFinish");
    });
  }
```

Maybe the WebView is interfering with the events of the window object, but Im not sure, I am new with Ionic. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `dispatchEvent` happens before your service initialization. And compare the event name `onLoadFinish` with `onJSLoadFinish`

Comment: Perhaps the dispatch is executed before, but the script loading is stucking all the app load (I cant even access the chrome inspect console until the loading finish). The names are correct in my code, that was a typo when I post the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered my problem. The event was dispatched before the service initialization, and the loading of the script file stucks all the app initialization including the service loading. So I solved by including the async attribute in the script tag:

```
<script async src="opencv.js" onload="loadFinish();" type="text/javascript">
```

So the service is loaded and is able to register the event listener while the script is  loading.